# How to print a file on a scheduled date?

Tags: java

I am working on printing a file with scheduled date (selected a date from datepicker) in Java, but I don't have any idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use cron based tasks that will fire and do the work. For your case, you may use [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on what actualy you do.
If you want to print many files in different time (printer queque in some oraginsation for example) you could follow next recomendation:

1) place all records about planned print in some storage (file, DB)

2) create one scheduler( @Scheduled in spring for example, or java sheduled executor) wich will processed queqe every minute(if minute is minmal interval of date that you could select).
(Be careful and select delay option instead of rate in your scheduler)

3) print only whose files that time to proceed.